# CorePlot plot hit testing

Tags: testing, core-plot, hit

I have a question about CorePlot. My question is:
I've drawn a curve. Next task is: curve selection.
I've added the handler:

But that does not work.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)npvCurveContainPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    if ([[graph allPlots] count] == 0) {
         return NO;
    }
    CPTPlot* plot = [graph plotAtIndex:0];
    BOOL xContains = [[plot plotRangeForCoordinate:CPTCoordinateX] containsDouble:point.x];
    BOOL yContains = [[plot plotRangeForCoordinate:CPTCoordinateY] containsDouble:point.y];
    if (xContains && yContains) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - Plot Space Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace*)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [graph convertPoint:point fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame];
    if ([self npvCurveContainPoint:pointInPlotArea]) {
        NSLog(@"Curve is selected!!!");
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to test, but you're mixing coordinate systems. The point passed to the plot space delegate method is in the **view** coordinates of the plot area layer. You convert it to the coordinate system of the entire graph layer and then test the point against the plot space **data** coordinates.

The plot space defines the mapping between the data and the plot area on screen. The `location` of the `xRange` corresponds to the left hand edge of the plot area and its end point (`location` + `length`) corresponds to the right hand edge. Similarly, the `location` of the `yRange` corresponds to the bottom edge of the plot area and its end point corresponds to the top edge. Note the plot ranges can have negative lengths, which means that the data coordinate of the end point can be less than the starting location.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Maybe I should explain what I want.
My task is checking if user has tapped on curve on not. I wish to solve the task without symbols.

Comment: What curve? The plot line, or something else?